# In YAML template validation fails to recognize "try"

Tags: aws-cloudformation

**Code:**

```
DEBUG_MODE = True  # Manually change when debugging
    try:
        CFN_CLIENT = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    except Exception as error:
        print('Error creating boto3.client, error text follows:\n%s' % error)
        raise Exception(error)
```

**Question:**

> Template validation error: Template format error: YAML not
>   well-formed. (line 37, column 1)

In my case (above code) the word "try" is placed at line 37 column 1.  I wonder what is not correct? Thanks.

Comment: 1) Your error message does not correspond to the code you show 2) show the relevant YAML file.